xgettext: Strings not extracted from a gtk4 builder file
xgettext is no extracting the translatable strings from my gtk4 builder file.
builder.glade:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
DO NOT EDIT!
This file was @generated by blueprint-compiler. Instead, edit the
corresponding .blp file and regenerate this file with blueprint-compiler.
-->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk" version="4.0"/>
  <object class="GtkApplicationWindow" id="window1">
    <property name="title">My App</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkGrid">
        <property name="row-spacing">10</property>
        <property name="column-spacing">10</property>
        <property name="margin-start">10</property>
        <property name="margin-end">10</property>
        <property name="margin-bottom">10</property>
        <property name="margin-top">10</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkEntry" id="entry1">
            <property name="hexpand">true</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="row">0</property>
              <property name="column">0</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton" id="button1">
            <property name="label" translatable="true">_Send</property>
            <property name="use-underline">true</property>
            <layout>
              <property name="row">0</property>
              <property name="column">1</property>
            </layout>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>

This is my xgettext command:
xgettext -o glade.pot -L Glade builder.glade

xgettext is not outputting the glade.pot file. Any ideas?

Xgettext has a problem with translatable="true", try translatable="yes".

The required syntax is translatable="yes", not translatable="true".

Sorry, this is the same as a comment to the question. Didn't see that.
